# Как сделать редирект запуска приложения Steam на определенное приложение

Tags: c#, shell, bat, steam

В общем, задача такая. При нажатии на ярлык стимовской игры steam://run/12345 нужно сделать чтобы включался Steam собственно и после запускалось другое приложение расположенное по такому-то такому-то адресу. И это нужно именно привязать как-то к ID игры.

Comment: 1. Заменить запускаемый файл (`.exe`) приложения на свой, который запустит игру и запустит нужную прогу. 2. Сделать программу, которая в фоне будет мониторить процессы и если найден процесс игры - запустить то, что надо еще. 3. Переопределить `steam://run/`, задав запуск всех игр через свое приложение, которое будет проверять id и делать нужную логику (запускать стим и открывать остальное необходимое).

Comment: К сожалению совершенно не знаком с тем как все это сделать:/ Было бы неплохо более подробную инфу или вариант более простой:(

Comment: Ну простите, я вроде написал максимально простые вещи. Как вы тогда собираетесь это делать, если ничего не знаете? Вот переименовать `.exe` файл, трудно что ли? Не прибедняйтесь тут, начинайте разбираться, задавайте более конкретные вопросы и вам помогут, а то, чего тогда вы здесь делаете, раз каждый ответ для вас будет "я не знаю, как это сделать"? Или вы хотите, чтоб за вас это все сделали? Ну тогда вам на фриланс, а не на SO.